# Having issue with .htaccess redirect wildcard rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have lots of URLs that need to be redirect in .htaccess. Our server is on a Shared VPS so we must using .htaccess file to do the redirects.
Old URL:**Cognitive_Direct_Thermal_Paper_Labels.html**
New URL:**cognitive-direct-thermal-paper-labels.html**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change the underscores to dashes but you can't make them lowercase with just htaccess

Comment: I have hundreds of pages like this example. What I need is a redirect wildcard so I don't have to put each individual url into .htaccess...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your URL looks like this:

```
http://example.com/Cognitive_Direct_Thermal_Paper_Labels.html
```

and needs to redirect to:

```
http://example2.com/cognitive-direct-thermal-paper-labels.html
```

You can handle all of those with a few rules but like I said, **you cannot change the capital letters to lowercase with only the htaccess file**.

So something like:

```
RewiteEngine On

# redirect if there are no underscores
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)\.html$ http://example2.com/$1.html [L.R]

# remove the underscores and change them to dashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)\.html$ /$1-$2.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched around and found out this. I have tested on my htaccess and the Uppercase to lowercase worked out pretty good. If anyone is reading this, just put the following codes on the top of your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```